# Understanding CSS Grouping/ Nesting

Tags: html, css, grouping, nested

I know similar questions to this have been asked a bunch of times but I could not find an answer for my specific one. If I have a bunch of CSS selectors that are very similar but are only just different how can I nest or group them.

Here is what I am trying to do.

```
 #cell-left {
  background-color:#DDDDDD; 
    border:2px solid;
    height:400px;
    margin:20px 10px 0px 32px; 
    padding: 40px 15px 15px 15px;
    text-align:center; 
 }
 #cell-center {
  background-color:#DDDDDD;
    border:2px solid; 
    height:400px;
    margin:20px 10px 0px 10px; 
    padding: 40px 15px 15px 15px;
    text-align:center; 
 }
 #cell-right {
  background-color:#DDDDDD;
    border:2px solid; 
    height:400px;
    margin:20px 32px 0px 20px;
    padding: 40px 15px 15px 15px; 
    text-align:center; 
 }
 #row {
  width:100%;
    margin-top:0px;
 }
```

As you can see all the cells are very common to each other they just have slightly different margins. I know there is a way to do all the cells the exact same then add a .right, .center and .left with just margin in the CSS and cut down on a lot of code.

Thanks in advance for the answer.

Comment: Also would it have been better to use Class selectors for these and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a cell class which contains the duplicate properties and add it to each of the DOM elements.

**CSS**

```
.cell{
   background-color:#DDDDDD; 
   border:2px solid;
   height:400px;
   padding: 40px 15px 15px 15px;
   text-align:center; 
}

#cell-left{
    margin:20px 10px 0px 32px; 
}

#cell-center {
    margin:20px 10px 0px 10px; 
}

#cell-right {
    margin:20px 32px 0px 20px;
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="cell-left" class="cell">Something</div>
<div id="cell-right" class="cell">Something</div>
<div id="cell-center" class="cell">Something</div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hKLMj/

Answer (score 2):

If you have just **one** left, center and right cell then you are fine with the *id*.

Otherwise use *classes*, since *id*-s **must** be unique and you can't have two elementswith the same *id* on the page.

And here is the shortened version of your CSS. Since your `cell`-s are some kind of children (let's assume they're `<td>`-s of a `<tr>` with class `.row`) - you don't have to use classes. This will make your markup cleaner:

```
tr.row td {
   background-color: #ddd; 
   border: 2px solid;
   height: 400px;
   padding: 40px 15px 15px 15px;
   text-align:center; 
   margin:20px 10px 0px 10px;
}
```

also if there are 3 of them in a `row` you don't have to use classes for defining left and right:

```
tr.row td:first-child {
    margin:20px 10px 0px 32px; /* left cell */
}

tr.row td:last-child {
    margin:20px 32px 0px 20px; /* right cell */
}
```

And the ***HTML*** will be

```
<tr class="row">
    <td> left cell </td>
    <td> center cell </td>
    <td> right cell </td>
</tr>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bn749/)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use class, it is the only way to group what you want. By the way, I guess you will have some pages with several identical cells and several rows, right ?

(I guess you know that, but in case : It is very bad practice to use twice a same id on a same page. Classes are meant to be used several times on a same page. And ids are meant to be used only once/page.

You can do this :

```
.cell {
  background-color:#DDDDDD; 
  border:2px solid;
  height:400px;
  padding: 40px 15px 15px 15px; 
  text-align:center; 
}
.cell-left {
  margin:20px 10px 0px 32px; 
}
.cell-center {
  margin:20px 10px 0px 10px; 
}
.cell-right {
  margin:20px 32px 0px 20px;
}
.row {
 width:100%;
 margin-top:0px;
}
```

And in you HTML you do this

```
<table border="1">
    <tr class="row">
        <td class="cell cell-left">row 1, cell 1</td>
        <td class="cell cell-right">row 1, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td class="cell cell-left">row 2, cell 1</td>
        <td class="cell cell-right">row 2, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can chain classes

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, and no I did not know it would be bad to use the same id, but now I do.

Comment: Great to know it helped ;) (Btw, if your question is answered, don't forget to validate the answer)

Comment: you can get rid of classes completely - they're not necessary here and just polluting the HTML markup

Answer (score 0):

CSS does not support grouping or nesting. Now, some CSS *compilers* (e.g. LESS, SASS) support such concepts as well as "mixins" and other neat tricks ..

.. however, remember that *all* matching CSS rules are applied. The selector specificity and order of declaration only decide which values override others. So, without classes or other hullabaloo:

```
#cell-left, #cell-center, #cell-right, #row {
    background-color:#DDDDDD; 
    border:2px solid;
    height:400px;
    padding: 40px 15px 15px 15px; 
}
#cell-left, #cell-center, #cell-right {
    text-align: center;
}

#cell-left {
    margin:20px 10px 0px 32px; 
}
#cell-center {
    margin:20px 10px 0px 10px; 
}
#cell-right { 
    margin:20px 32px 0px 20px;
}
#row {
    width:100%;
    margin-top:0px;     
}
```

Now, while it might be beneficial to use classes or a cleaner markup - especially if doing so leads to easier maintenance - the above will achieve the same result as the initial post. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

It will be more semantically correct to use [double class selectors](https://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/#article-header-id-2):

```
.cell {
    background-color: #DDDDDD; 
    border: 2px solid;
    height: 400px;
    padding: 40px 15px 15px 15px;
    text-align: center; 
}
.cell.left {
    margin: 20px 10px 0px 32px; 
}
.cell.center {
    margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px; 
}
.cell.right {
    margin: 20px 32px 0px 20px;
}
```

This way you will be able to write:

```
<div class="cell left">Something</div>
<div class="cell center">Something</div>
<div class="cell right">Something</div>
```

Or even:

```
<div class="left cell">Something</div>
<div class="center cell">Something</div>
<div class="right cell">Something</div>
```